# Settings icon for the Chrome Control no longer displays in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, office-365

We make use of the Control Control for our SharePoint Add-Ins, and it looks like the Settings icon for the upper right menu is now missing.
 On further examination, the URL for the image returns a SharePoint error screen.

https://somedomain/apptest/_layouts/15/defaultcss.ashx?ctag=1522964650769&resource=spcommon

[image: Missing Setting Icon from Chrome]

Any chance anyone else has had this issue with their Add-Ins? I suspect some of the underlying shifts in SharePoint Online's UIs may have broke the Chrome Control capability, and I'm hoping someone on the SharePoint team could investigate.

Reference Question: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint-Developer/It-looks-like-the-Settings-icon-for-the-Chrome-Control-no-longer/td-p/179938